# Showing the sequence $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}}, \dots$ tends to $2$ using the Epsilon-Neighbourhood definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am given the sequence
$$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 a_n}, \quad a_1 = \sqrt{2}.$$
That is, the sequence
$$ \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}}, \dots$$

I am aware of using the recursive method to find the limit: setting $x = \sqrt{2x}$ and getting $x = 2$, rejecting $x = 0$ due to the sequence being monotone and positive.

I now want to show that the limit of this sequence is $2$ using the epsilon-neighbourhood definition for a convergent series:

> Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence that converges to a real number $a$. Then, for every number $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a number $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $|a_n - a| < \epsilon$.

I take the logarithm on both sides and arrive at
$$ \left| \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n} \right) \ln 2 - \ln 2 \right|  < \epsilon. $$

Using triangle inequality, $|x - y| \geq |x| - |y|$, I arrive at
$$ \left| \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n} \right) \right| - |\ln 2| < \epsilon. $$

Add $\ln 2$ to both sides
$$ \left| \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n} \right) \right| < \epsilon + \ln 2. $$

The left hand side can be rewritten as a sum of $n$ terms in a geometric series with first term $\frac{1}{2}$ and common ratio $\frac{1}{2}$,
$$ \frac{\frac{1}{2} \left( 1 - \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^n \right)}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^n} < \epsilon + \ln 2. $$
I am unsure of how to proceed beyond this point.

Comment: line 4 is wrong.

Comment: Line 4 as in invoking the triangle inequality, or invoking the sum for a geometric series?

Comment: Diverges very slowly though. You can easily prove without delta epsilon, by solving $x=\sqrt {2x}$. You will also need to prove x not 0

Comment: You did not apply the triangle inequality correctly.

Comment: @kangzhe as in forgetting a factor in one summand

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see my mistake now; I should have written $|\ln 2| - \left| \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n} \right) \ln 2 \right| > \epsilon$ since that geometric sum is less than $1$, making $\ln 2 > \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n}\right) \ln 2$.

Comment: No, you should have written $(\ln 2) |\frac 1 2+\frac  1 4+..+\frac1 {2^{n}}-1| <\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

For $n>1$, we can write

$$\frac{a_n}2=2^{-2^{-n}}>2^{-\frac1n}>1-\frac1n$$ because $2^n>n$ and because by the binomial theorem

$$\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{-n}>\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=1+\frac nn+\frac{n(n-1)}{2n^2}+\cdots+1>2.$$

Now it suffices to prove convergence of $1-\dfrac1n$ to $1$, which is easy, and will allow to write

$$n>N\implies\left|2-\frac2n\right|<\epsilon\implies\left|2^{1-2^{-n}}-2\right|<\epsilon.$$

The figure illustrates the first inequalities.

[image]

Comment: If my understanding is correct, it's because the inequality is $1 - \frac{1}{2^n} < 1  - \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$, solving the inequality of the last two terms will fulfill the definition?

Comment: @kangzhe: you understand the idea, but did not copy the right inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Let's make an observation: for each natural number $n$, your sequence can be given explicitly by $$a_n = 2^{\sum_{i=1}^n (\frac{1}{2})^i}$$

For example, $a_2 = \sqrt{2\sqrt{2}} = (2(2^{1/2}))^{1/2} = 2^{1/2} \cdot 2^{1/4} = 2^{1/2 + 1/4}$

Furthermore, we know that $${\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i} \to 1 \ \ \text{as} 
 \ \ n \to \infty$$

We also know that the function $f(x) = 2^x$ is a continuous function. In other words, if we pick $\epsilon > 0$, there is $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-1| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(1)|< \epsilon$.

Thus, because $$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i \to 1$$there is $M > 0$ so that $n > M$ implies $$\left|{\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i -1}\right| < \delta$$

Hence, letting $x = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i$ in the paragraph where I mentioned continuity, we obtain $$\left|f\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^i\right) - 2\right| < \epsilon$$

This is precisely $|a_n -2 | < \epsilon$

Comment: This is not truly an $\epsilon/\delta$ proof, as it uses a theorem on continuity - of a transcendental function.

Comment: It can be made into a "true" $\epsilon-\delta$ proof. For a precise value of $\delta$, one can see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1583060 where we choose $x_0 = 1$. Once $\delta$ is chosen, choose $M > \frac{\ln(\delta^{-1})}{\ln(2)}$

Comment: Yes, "it can". But it is not. And one should also prove continuity of the exponential.

Comment: If one cares about this level of pedantry, I have provided $M$ and an easy source for where to find $\delta$. Read the link for continuity of the exponential

Comment: The problem is not with the estimates of the bounds. It is with the proof principle.

Comment: Oh please, at some point we all have to take certain results for granted. I'm sorry if my proof doesn't include all the necessary details. I guess we should start this proof by constructing the real numbers...

Comment: You might as well invoke the fixed-point theorem to establish the claim, or whatnot. But the request is clearly about an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof.