# How to check the convergence or divergence of sequence $\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3\sqrt{3}},\sqrt{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3}},\dots$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I tried like this

$a_n=\sqrt{3\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3}\dots}$ $n-times$

Taking square of the both sides

$(a_n)^2=3a_{n-1}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{(a_n)^2}{a_{n-1}}=3$

But I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: The sequence in the header is not the same as the one in the body of your post.  Which one did you intend?  And...what have you tried?  A natural first step is to assume the limit exists and then use the recursion to compute it, worrying about existence after.

Comment: Possibly [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4018603/showing-the-sequence-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-sqrt2-dot?rq=1)

Comment: You have the limit as $n\to\infty$ of $3^{\frac{1}{2}}3^{\frac{1}{4}}\dots 3^{\frac{1}{2^n}}$ and since $f(x)=3^x$ is continuous you have $3$ raised to the limit of that sum.

Comment: I cannot figure out how a_n is defined from the wording of the question.

Comment: Do we want the third term to be $\sqrt{\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3}}$ or do we want $\sqrt{\sqrt{3\sqrt{3}}}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a_n$ can also be expressed in terms of exponent notation.
$$a_n=\sqrt{3}\times\sqrt{\sqrt{3}}\times\ldots\times\sqrt{\sqrt{\ldots\sqrt{3}}}\\
=3^\frac{1}{2}\times3^\frac{1}{4}\times\ldots\times3^\frac{1}{2^n}\\
=3^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2^n}}\\
\stackrel{\text{geometric sum}}{=}3^{1-\frac{1}{2^n}}$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}3^{1-\frac{1}{2^n}}\\
=3^{1-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}}\\
=3^{1-0}=3$$

This shows that $a_n$ converges to 3.